# Rails uniqueness validation with unless condition unwanted behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, unique, conditional-statements

I have this following validation in Playlist model with attributes title and is_deleted. The point of the 'is_deleted' column(bool type column with default value 'false') is cause I have to archive 
the playlists not delete them.

```
validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: true, unless: :is_deleted?
```

Now if I have a record for example with title 'Playlist 1' and is_deleted false and try to create a record with is_deleted: true it won't validate him, which is good. If I try to update the is_deleted column from the first record to true it won't validate, which is good as well.
But here is the thing now I have two playlists with title: "Playlist 1" and is_deleted: true. If I try to update any of them to is_deleted: false, the validation won't let me. It gives a "Title has already been taken" error. I really don't understand why, cause I don't have any other record that is is_deleted: false with the title: "Playlist 1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because your validation is checking for the uniqueness of `:title` only. When it validates your model after changing `is_deleted` to `false` it is checking that the title is unique. It'll do a query something like:

```
Playlist.where(title: 'Playlist 1').where.not(id: self.id).exists?
```

and obviously there *is* a playlist with that title already.

The key thing is that it doesn't check the `is_deleted` flag on *other* playlists. It is only using it on the current playlist to decide whether it should validate or not.

You probably need to us [`validates_uniqueness_of`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of) rather than just `validates` which means you can add conditions to the validation:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :title, 
  unless: :is_deleted?, 
  conditions: -> { where(is_deleted: false) }
```

This will ensure that your uniqueness check only checks against other playlists that are also not deleted.

You need to keep your `validates :title, presence: true, unless: :is_deleted?` to validate that the title is present (or you may have some success with the `allow_nil` or `allow_blank` options on `validates_uniqueness_of`).

Comment: Can't you add `:conditions` on generic `validates` as well?

Comment: It doesn't appear so from the api docs. I guess there's room for confusion with the different validations that the plain `validates` supports.

Comment: Thanks really, awesome explanation, anyway @SergioTulentsev, you must use validates_(something)_of in order to use the conditions options.

Comment: @VlatkoRistovski: I maintain that database-enforced constraints are the right way to go (if the DB supports it, that is). This app-level check is vulnerable to race conditions.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, me too, but I also use the app-level validations as well.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev There are benefits to having both database constraints and application level constraints aren't there? It's not a question of one or the other.

Comment: @Shadwell: yes, of course. I was merely pointing out that with only app-level constraint there's no guarantee. It's a time bomb.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, I've kinda learned that the hard way. I was just wondering for this, cause with unique partial index on title this is pretty easy to accomplish. Please correct me if I'm wrong  
     add_index :playlists, :title, unique: true, where: 'is_deleted = false'

Comment: @VlatkoRistovski: I'm not sure about rails syntax for this. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Well this is what it should generate.  
`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX playlists(_some_name_idx) ON playlists (title) WHERE is_deleted = 'false';`
Just checking if I'm on the right track? :)

Comment: @VlatkoRistovski: you are :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So this actually "validates uniqueness of title among only non-deleted records" ?

Comment: With a partial index - yes. With `validates` in your question - no.

Answer (score 3):

This `unless` runs in ruby-land. And it does what it says on the tin: "validate uniqueness of title if post is not deleted". Note that it doesn't say "validate uniqueness of title among only non-deleted records".

You should be using database tools to enforce this kind of restrictions. Postgres has [partial unique indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) that can do this.